# php display data from database according to html toggle switch

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I've one page called **test.php** that display 2 types of products, first type is **Odd** second type is **Even**, the page have one HTML Switch/Toggle

**Note(** the code work OK and it display results according to switch/toggle value **)**

I've 1 issue

**Code run's ok but it duplicate the switch/toggle (See Images Bellow)**

.

**test.php**

```
<?php
require ('../../common.php');
echo "
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/toggleOddEven.css'>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

to load default odd products on page load

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function() {
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'test.php',
    data:{
        product_type:'odd'
        },
    success: function(data){
    $('#view').html(data);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Switch/Toggle value

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
$('#myonoffswitch').click(function() {
    if ($('#myonoffswitch').prop('checked')) {

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'test.php',
            data:{
                product_type:'even'
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#view').html(data);
            }
        });
    }else{

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'test.php',
            data:{
                product_type:'odd'
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#view').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Rest of page code

```
</head>
<body>

<div class='onoffswitch'>
<input type='checkbox' name='onoffswitch' class='onoffswitch-checkbox' id='myonoffswitch'>
<label class='onoffswitch-label' for='myonoffswitch'>
    <span class='onoffswitch-inner'></span>
    <span class='onoffswitch-switch'></span>
</label>
</div>

<div id='view'></div>

</body>
</html>
";
if (isset($_POST['product_type'])) {
$product_type = $_POST['product_type'];
$allProducts="SELECT * FROM products_tbl 
            WHERE product_type = :product_type ";
$stmt = $db->prepare($allProducts);
$query_params = array( 
            ':product_type' => $product_type 
        );
$stmt->execute($query_params);

$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($data as $value):
    echo "
        <strong># </strong> <a href='prod?id=".$value['product_name']."'>".$value['product_name']."</a> </br>
    ";
endforeach;

}

?>
```

why it duplicate the tag ? see bellow image

[odd product (default value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIByW.jpg)

[even product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukqdy.jpg)

Comment: What you mean by `tag` here? Can you make a jsfiddle to explain your problem?

Comment: @CodeThing jsfiddle not shoing the problem, please see the attached error (its duplicate the switch/toggle i want just one switch/toggle and it showing 2 as the image i attached) 


and i mean checkbox `tag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you load the whole page in test.php, not only the result data. This should help:

```
if (isset($_POST['product_type'])) {
  --> keep existing code
} else {
  --> Put your large echo into here
  echo "
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/toggleOddEven.css'>
  ...
  ";
}
```

A cleaner solution might be to split the data and the UI into seperate PHP files and only request the data PHP.

Comment: marked as accepted :) thanks its solve the problem perfectly, but what do y mean by separate php files ?